# What is the oldest known record of meditation?

Tags: meditation

Meditation is when you focus your attention on a clear mind. You eliminate thoughts that may be distracting and cause stress.

I meditate for around 30 minutes a day, it is a great way to prepare for something hard/challenging.

But, when was the first time someone did this? It seems like this could have been going on since the dinosaur age, but I want to know if there is any solid proof.

I know there is probably not going to be an answer that is exactly correct, but I am asking for one that has proof. Thanks for the time and effort put in to answer!

Comment: Interesting question, although I think many/most practitioners of meditation may disagree with your definition of meditation (naturally, I can only speak with relative certainty for myself).  Your definition is a common starting point (I certainly had the same definition at one time), but I do feel that particular definition discourages the practice of meditation.  I encourage you (and all) with that definition of meditation to learn more about meditation.  I write these kind words for you because I wish someone wrote them for me many years ago.

Comment: You really won't get an answer worth anything, in my opinion. Meditation, prayer, shamanism, and other mystical practices have been documented in various ways dating back to perhaps 3000 to 5000 BC. Anytime you stop and stare at the moon and the stars, that's meditation. That implies it was always a thing. Intentional meditation for the purpose of achieving an altered mental state is another thing. That probably arose with shamanism and mystical practices, which we know probably existed even before homo sapiens existed.

Comment: Also, dinosaurs and humans never roamed the earth at the same time. By the time humans came along, dinosaurs had not been seen on the planet for 64 million years. The depictions on TV and in movies showing primitive "cavemen" running into caves to avoid the dinosaurs are totally made up. Minor nitpick. Haha.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think this isn't really about martial arts. A lot of them include meditation and can get you into flow-like states and martial arts which use them should mention it in historic manuals, but I am not sure we are the SE site for this

Comment: First meditation is probably from the jain tradition... Which is quite close to Hinduism?  Maybe rather than closing we can migrate the question to the Hinduism stack exchange?

Comment: @PipperChip closing it now would do no good, there's already a perfectly good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Positive Psychology's heavily-referenced article, ***The History and Origin of Meditation*** (2019) states:

> The oldest documented images of meditation are from India and date back to 5000 to 3500 BCE. Wall art paintings depict people sitting in meditative-like seated postures with their eyes half closed, presumed to be deep in meditation.
>
> The oldest documented text of meditation is also from India, from the Hindu traditions of Vendatism, from around 1500 BCE. Although the Vedas created texts describing meditative practices it’s important to know that these had previously been passed down orally through storytelling practices for centuries.

A comment from a reader beneath the main article's text claims:

> Meditation & yoga date back to before humanity left Alkebulan. Indian writings found date back to before 10,000 BC.

I couldn't find any reputable sources which backed up this claim, but it is quite possible that meditation existed in some form or another long before anyone decided to record the practice via art or text, or that the earliest depictions of meditation in art that have survived are far younger than the earliest depictions that were ever created.

Meditation is a loose term describing a lot of similar practices; some of which attempt to expel thought, others of which attempt to simply be mindful of how thoughts enter and exit the mind. Some practices are performed in peace and quiet. Other forms are practiced throughout the moment-to-moment waking experience and yet others attempt to move the practice into sleep. With this in mind, meditation likely existed long before any name was given to the practice, and possibly even before people were even aware that they were 'doing a thing' that might be worthy of a name.

As for the earliest practices of meditation as an element of the martial arts, easily accessible 'evidence' online is poorly referenced. Claims of a relationship with Taoism and Buddhism seem common, along with links to the 5th Century AD and later.